# Foreach on 2D Array Doesn't Produce Output

Tags: php, class, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a function inside a PHP class that reads as follows:

```
  //properties
  var $title;
  var $thePage;

      function gBuildTable($theArray){
        //given a 2D array, builds an HTML table based on that array
        $table = "<table> \n";
        foreach ($theArray as $row){
          $table .= "<tr> \n";
          foreach ($row as $cell){
            $table .= "  <td>$cell</td> \n";
          } // end foreach
          $table .= "</tr> \n";
        } // end foreach
        $table .= "</table> \n";

        return $table;
      } // end gBuildTable

      function buildTable($theArray){
        $temp = $this->gBuildTable($theArray);
        $this->addText($temp);
      } // end buildTable

      function addText($content){
        //given any text (including HTML markup)
        //adds the text to the page
        $this->thePage .= $content;
        $this->thePage .= "\n";
      } // end addText

      function gAddText($content){
        //given any text (including HTML markup)
        //returns the text
        $temp= $content;
        $temp .= "\n";
        return $temp;
      } // end addText
```

So then I have a bunch of data which I build into a 2D array as such (hopefully its correct structure):

```
    $data = array(
        array("Name", $name),
        array("Email", $email),
        array("Hobby", $hobby),
        array("", $stamp)
    );
    $obj = &New sH;   //the class name
    $obj->buildTable($data);
```

Am I making some boneheaded oversight or something that I am not seeing? This doesn't produce anything, it LITERALLY comes back empty. No errors, No warning, No notices, NADA.

FYI: The variables such as `$name` have all been previously initialized and set, they are NOT NULL. Any assistance as to what I am doing wrong, would be greatly appreciated. TIA

PS. I used `current()` inside the `foreach` loop to echo out what it is seeing at that time, and it sees the data, so I am at a loss why its not actually doing anything.

### Update [SOVLED]

I can't believe I missed it and no one else caught it, but its OK, part of the wonderful world that is coding. I resolved it by noticing that its missing ONE line to grab the internal object that is being built:

```
echo $obj->$thePage;
```

Comment: Make sure that error_reporting and display_errors are set properly and also take a look at your error log.  A white page output from PHP usually represents an error.  Since your code is incomplete, it's not possible for me to test it.

Comment: There is more than enough there and I solved it myself, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `echo $table;` in your function..!

or store the value the function is returning and echo in your main code.

```
$data = array(
    array("Name", $name),
    array("Email", $email),
    array("Hobby", $hobby),
    array("", $stamp)
    );

$obj = &New sH;   //the class name
$table = $obj->buildTable($data);
echo $table;
```

Comment: While I am almost 100% certain that is unnecessary when using a class, I went ahead and tried it for sake of being able to say for certain that it didn't do anything, thank you though.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  I'm not sure what you mean though "unnecessary when using a class", are you referring to storing the result of your buildTable function or echoing it?  

It looks like your solution was to just echo the `$obj->buildTable($data)`.  That's essentially what I meant, I suppose I shouldn't have said "you need to store it", just that you need to echo it somewhere.

I'm interested to learn what you tried, and why it wouldn't work.

Comment: What I meant is that **THIS** class, I should have been more specific, doesn't return anything just maintains everything internally, so I had to actually `echo` out the variable its holding INTERNALLY. Of course that's not always the case. Your approach was logically sound, just not for this particular gizmo :)

Comment: What I ended up realizing is that none of the functions do an actual return of anything to outside of the class scope, rather its appending it internally to an object that it presumably after you did everything you needed would make that object and all contents available to  you. This is actually one of the most horribly dated class I have seen in a long time, BUT, unfortunately it has been made a requirement to use it.

Comment: gotcha..! Thanks for clarifying :-)

Comment: Thank you. And because your thinking was in spirit the same  as the solution, I am going to go ahead and mark it so you can get some due and bump your rep a bit.

Comment: Thanks man... it would be nice to be able to comment on a post every now and then :-)

Comment: You are most welcome, I know that a lot of good people get hampered on the site simply because of rep, I have been there and in some cases, still am, so when I can help get a helpful person moving up, that's always good for everyone.